# Run function in ViewModel when TextBox loses focus?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I currently have the following code to define a TextBox in a grid (the grid is populated based on data, so is also inside a DataTemplate):

```
<TextBox 
    MinWidth="120" 
    Text="{Binding BatchNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ToolTip="Redacted" 
    IsTabStop="True"
    MaxLength="32" 
    <!-- LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" -->
/>
```

I'd like to run a function in my ViewModel when the textbox loses focus. Using the LostFocus property, and binding to a function name, causes a runtime error of:

> A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject

As such, I'm looking for details on how to run a ViewModel function when focus is lost.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel try to add:

```
//Public property
public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

//In the constructor 
MyCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSometing);

//Private method to handle lost focus
private void DoSometing(){
//Do someting
}
```

Then call MyCommand in your xaml.

```
LostFocus="{Binding MyCommand}"
```

Comment: Has to be ViewModel unfortunately

Comment: Where does the MyCommand = new RelayCommand section need to go?

Comment: In the constructor for your ViewModel. 
Sorry about the text formatting issues.

Comment: I get the runtime error `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'AddLostFocusHandler' property of type 'TextBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'`